# Django ORM: Force an outer join to unused table

Tags: python, mysql, django

For all of the below, I am using Django 1.9.

I have a Django model that looks something like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  task_count = models.FloatField()
  requesters = models.ManyToManyField('Requester', through='ProjectRequester')

class ProjectRequester(models.Model):
  project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
  requester = models.ForeignKey('Requester')

class Requester(models.Model):
  username = models.CharField()
```

I have a form that allows the user to get the total task count for all projects or to group the task count by either name or requester.  This works totally fine if you group by name.  You get a queryset that looks something like this:

```
qs = Project.objects.select_related().values('name')
qs = qs.annotate(task_count=models.Sum('task_count'))
```

The SQL produced is exactly as you'd expect, something like:

```
SELECT SUM(Project.task_count) FROM Project GROUP BY Project.Name;
```

However, because of the many-to-many join with requester, when you pivot by requester, any project that has more than 1 requester gets its tasks double-counted.  This:

```
qs = Project.objects.select_related().values('requesters__username')
qs = qs.annotate(task_count=models.Sum('task_count'))
```

Leads to this:

```
SELECT SUM(Project.task_count) FROM Project
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjectRequester ON ProjectRequester.ProjectId=Project.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Requester ON Requester.Id=ProjectRequester.RequesterId
GROUP BY Requester.Username;
```

I absolutely do not want to drop down to using raw sql, for a lot of reasons.  So my initial thought was to store the number of requesters as a field on the Project model (`requester_count = models.FloatField()`) which gets populated automatically when the project is loaded into the table.  This way, I could change the second line of the queryset creation above to:

```
task_count = models.Sum(models.ExpressionWrapper(
    models.F('task_count') / models.F('requester_count')
qs = qs.annotate(task_count=task_count)
```

This produces the desired result:

```
SELECT SUM(Project.task_count / Project.requester_count) FROM Project
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjectRequester ON ProjectRequester.ProjectId=Project.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Requester ON Requester.Id=ProjectRequester.RequesterId
GROUP BY Requester.Username;
```

Yay!  However, there's actually a lot of other stuff going on here (about 20 other ways you can actually pivot, plus the ability to filter by any combindation of some of these fields) so it's not as simple as simply adding an `if pivot == 'name', use regular sum annotation, else use sum divided by requester count` (because using the 2nd annotation will not produce the correct number of tasks if the LEFT OUTER JOIN doesn't happen).

So that leads me to my question: is there some way I can force Django to always add the LEFT OUTER JOIN with the ProjectRequester table, even if there is no filter or group by with that table?  That way, I could always just simply divide by the requester_count, regardless of pivot or filter, and the math would always work out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One idea is to add an annotation on the `ProjectRequester` table that I don't actually use: `qs.annotate(task_count=models.Sum('task_count'), force_join=models.Count('requesters'))`.  That seems to work, although I don't know how much latency adding an unused `COUNT()` to the query adds....

Comment: I'll probably just do the if / else logic.  It's a little more complicated, but the slowdown in the queries by always joining with ProjectRequester when you didn't need to doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: have you tried using [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) like `qs = Project.objects.select_related().values('requesters__username').distinct()`?